# Why here error comes in ternary Operator?

Tags: java

The below statement gives error "unexpected type"

```
int i = 3;
System.out.println( (i==3) ? i+=3 : i-=3);
```

why this happens ?

Comment: Try `System.out.println( (3==3) ? (i+=3) : (i-=3));`

Comment: With extra parentheses it works: `System.out.println( (3==3) ? (i+=3) : (i-=3));` but no one would usually write code like this. It looks like a mistake. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @khelwood I almost always use parentheses like that. I prefer to have my code be understood several months after I wrote it.

Comment: @NomadMaker I wasn't saying the use of parentheses was odd. I was saying that putting `i+=3` and `i-=3` inside a conditional expression was odd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's due to [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html): the `+=` and `-=` assignment operators have lower precedence than the `? :` ternary conditional expression operator.

There is only one way to interpret the `i+=3` because it's followed by a `:`, namely, as the first branch of the ternary. But the `-=3` is ambiguous and resolved according to precedence. Because the ternary has higher precedence, the expression is parsed like this:

```
((3==3) ? (i+=3) : i) -= 3
```

which is obviously nonsense, because you cannot assign to the result of an expression.

It works if you add extra parentheses to make the assignments take precedence:

```
(3==3) ? (i+=3) : (i-=3)
```

The parentheses around `i+=3` are optional but recommended for readability (insofar as this thing is ever going to be readable).

Comment: It seems to work with parenthesis just around the (i-=3).

Comment: @matt because += has higher precedence over -=,we don't have to explicitly put brackets over +=

Comment: @GiritejaBille I don't get your point. It isn't the += vs -= that matters it's the relationship of the ? : vs += or -=. Only the second one needs to be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: @matt Interesting observation! That sheds more light on what the parser is doing. I've edited the answer.